# Server to stream webcam to local network in a format embeddable on webpage

Tags: windows, linux, javascript, html, webcam

I want to create a "surveillance" cam on my door step with next requirements:

- I want to have a webpage locally accessible on my network.
- I want to be able to live stream video from my USB webcam to the webpage.
- I also want to have some other stuff displayed on the page such as clock, weather etc. (I have this part figured out).

I don't have any idea on how to stream a USB webcam to a webpage.

Operating system: Windows or Linux

Comment: VLC has a http streaming server built into it.  There is also `ffmpeg` and `ffserver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [OBS Studio by Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) which can capture any video source on your computer and stream it to anywhere you want, including built-in streams for Twitch, YouTube Live and other such services.  OBS Studio is free and it is fantastic software!

You'll configure OBS Studio to stream to an RTMP server, which you can run from Linux or Windows.  There is a lot of material to assist with this part, such as [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqK73yS_h7c).

And you can capture any portion of a desktop and add insets to your main source, like a clock, weather etc.